# bizarre behavior of system() in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, shell

I have set up shuffle_play.rb in Ruby by Example to work on Windows, with mpg123 instead of ogg123. The critical part is a method called play_file, which initially I wrote like this

```
def play_file(file)
  system("mpg123 \"#{file}\"")
end
```

I have mpg123 in the same directory as my script ... it didn't work. But this does work:

```
def play_file(file)
  system("mpg123.exe \"#{file}\"")
end
```

I reckon it's because I don't have working directory in %PATH% (and indeed the problem goes away when I add it) but even then I don't know enough about Windows to know the difference. Could someone explain the rationale for this?

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Ruby are you using? The behavior of system() changed in Ruby 1.9.x and behaves more properly than 1.8.x counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the examples assume that you're on a *nix variant such as Linux or Mac. In those Operating Systems, the program is called `mpg123`, because those OS, don't care about extensions, the just check that the file has an executable attribute

On windows things are very different. Windows decides if something is a program depending on the extension (.exe, .com, .bat, .cmd, etc.). So the program in windows has to be called `mpg123.exe`. If you open a command line on windows, you can run the program without specifying the extension, as windows automatically tries the different extensions. This behaviour of trying different extensions happens **ONLY** in the command line and not when you try to invoke a program from another one.

There a environment variable called PATHEXT that list in which order windows tries the different extensions. On my computer that list is:

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.RB;.RBW
```

I hope it was clear. And a suggestion if you want to code in ruby, install Linux or get a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This explained me, why I had to add `rube.exe` in front of my ruby scripts, when I wanted to start them via `system` or from a bat-file.

Comment: "If you open a command line on windows, you can run the program without specifying the extension, as windows automatically tries the different extensions."

The file was in fact called "mpg123.exe". Thanks for your answer, but I'm unclear on why I need to invoke "mpg123.exe" when the working directory is NOT in %PATH% but only "mpg123" when it is.

Also, Linux and Mac are great suggestions but I'm at uni, without my own comp ... PyCmd has done wonders for me and if I really needed it I could install MinGW or something. Windows is fine for my purposes.

Comment: I now understand your question. I just tried what you mentioned and I also don't understand why ruby needs the extension when the the file is not on the PATH. As a side note, I tested this on Java and I got the same results (file without extension => error), so it might be the way that windows resolves the program location/name. It's a bit late here, otherwise I would try doing the same on C# :).